# Merge multiple vertices in a directed graph of boost graph library c++

Tags: c++, graph-theory, boost-graph, directed-graph

I am new to Boost graph library(BGL) in C++. Is there an easy way to merge MULTIPLE vertices in a directed graph which was constructed using BGL? I am using the following example code to construct my directed graph - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/graph/example/quick_tour.cpp

Thanks

Comment: Why is `MULTIPLE in capitals? Are you able to merge SINGLE vertices? DUAL vertices? What is the goal? Because, you know, C++ is Turing complete and BGL is pretty generic. The answer is gonna be "yes".

Comment: Merging two vertices would involve two calls to add_edge() and one call to remove_vertex(). I was wondering if there is an easy way to avoid this step? Does BGL has a function to merge vertices?